# Getting file name of file directed by .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, image, dynamic

I'm making a dynamic image for a forum that doesn't allow dynamic images.

I tried using .htacess to redirect all *.png files to image.png... which works perfectly, but from here I can't seem to be able to get the filename of the .png that was requested to generate the content.

For example:

1. user puts in banana.png
2. htaccess forwards to image.php

I need a way of getting that banana into my php script.

Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` just returns that of the PHP file.

Is there a way of redirecting it to `image.php?=bananana` for example?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. You should be able to access the image path at $_GET['image']. Added ability to preserve existing query string if need be, (but the image key would obviously be overridden).

If you are still getting 404, I don't know what to say. I tested this and it works for me.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.png)$ image.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&image=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi eyelidlessness, I just get a 404 Not found error message for all PNG files with that code =(

Comment: how odd, still cant seem to get it to work =(

I guess I just have a dodgy server? 
Thank you for your help anyway =D


I managed to get...
/img.php?id=/ipboard/dynaimage/989890.png
from...
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*\.png)$ /img.php?id=$1

Comment: Huh. Maybe mod_rewrite is not enabled? Or maybe my rewrite should go to /img.php. I dunno. If it works, it works. Toodles.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.png$ image.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If this doesn't work, you likely don't have mod_rewrite enabled.